# How can I track who is on my computer?

Tags: gratis, windows-7, logs

I get annoyed because whenever I leave my computer to get a drink my friend will go on it and do something like freeze the mouse (Fn+F7) or turn on Scroll Lock (Fn+Scr Lk). When I come back he acts all innocent and it is hard to find what he has done. Is there a program to silently log all the keystrokes that is made?

It should be unnoticeable so he doesn't think anything is up. Then when I get back to my computer I will see what key strokes he has made. I am running windows 7 32-bit and looking for something free. Thanks.

Comment: Lock your workstation.

Comment: @GregHewgill the password for all the computers at where I am talking about is the same and we aren't allowed to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are key logger programs - which are mostly used for poaching passwords - hence most companies ban them - and they cannot tell who is on the computer unless that person types in their name.

The only way of logging **who** has been on your computer is to record from a web camera but having that running all the time would use a huge amount of disc space and mostly just record you sitting at your computer.

Since there are some things that could be done that are more than just pranks, e.g. Deleting important files, loading dodgy files, sending rude emails to everybody from your account, then you should **always** lock your computer - hold the windows key and press L - before leaving it.

Comment: the password for all the computers at where I am talking about is the same and we aren't allowed to change it. Thanks though.

Comment: Then you need to raise this issue with the administrator & security controller __ASAP__ - in that set-up there only takes one disgruntled user to trash the entire system and there is no way of knowing who has performed malicious actions.

Comment: Good idea. Since it's the end of the year I probably won't. I think that they just don't want people to forget their passwords and additional complications.

Comment: There is always a certain amount of kudos from "I __told__ you so _X_ months ago!"